# Remodelar um titulo para algo mais simples

Tags: debate, perguntas, edição, título

É cabível remodelar um titulo para algo mais simples e passar o titulo original para o corpo da pergunta? Vejam esta pergunta: [Ao desconstruir um one-liner baseado em perl ocorre o erro "Can't modify single ref constructor in scalar assignment"](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/66750/estou-tentando-desconstruir-um-one-liner-baseado-em-perl-porem-como-n%C3%A3o-tenho-c). Seu titulo é gigante e não possui uma descrição do erro no corpo da mensagem.

Comment: Relacionado: [Edição de título para melhorar em buscas](http://meta.pt.stackoverflow.com/q/3827/3117)

Comment: com certeza... titulos como esse deve ser simplificado.